# How to implement a servlet to submit job to Hadoop 2.6.0 cluster

Tags: java, servlets, hadoop

I'm trying to  run a servlet (QueryServlet) - using Tomcat 8- which submits  a job called "ArqOnHadoop2" to hadoop 2.6.0... this last one is configured using single node setting up in /usr/local folder. 
This job works if i start it from command line but, when i try to execute the follow code from netbeans,I receive "HTTP Status 500 - Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses."

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml"));
config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml"));

config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());            
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address","master:8032");
config.set("mapreduce.framework.name","yarn");
config.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://master:9000");

//input query parameter as string
config.set(ArqReducerConstants.MY_QUERY,args[0]);

Job job = Job.getInstance(config);
job.setJarByClass(QueryServlet.class);
//input number of lines for mapper parameter as int, used to reduce number of splits and run map() method quickly
String N=args[4];
int n=Integer.parseInt(N);
job.getConfiguration().setInt(NLineInputFormat.LINES_PER_MAP, n);

job.setMapperClass(MapperDoesNothing.class);
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(TripleWritable.class);

job.setReducerClass(QueryReducer.class);

job.setInputFormatClass( BlockedNTriplesInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
String in="hdfs://master:9000"+args[1];
String out="hdfs://master:9000"+args[2];
//input and output paths parameters
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(in));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(out));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

//where `args` is just a name of a String array with some input parameters..

There are no problems with hadoop or in the .xml files;
there are no problems with permissions, because i've disable its with: dfs.permission.enables=false in hdfs-site.xml;
there are no problem with permissions also for my hadoop folder because i've used `chmod -R 777`;

So...what does my project miss to obtain the goal? I need help...

Thanks in advance,
Carmen.